# Get keys using Lodash with only partial key string

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

Is it possible to use LoDash `_.filter` to return values if you only know a key contains a certain string? So let's say you have the following data:

```
Mydata{
"banana" : "1"
}
```

And I want to return the values that contain "ana"? Everything I found on LoDash is mostly about searching the element values but not the keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get an array of the values, which keys conform to a criterion,
Lodash's [`_.filter()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) works with objects as well. The 2nd param passed to the callback is the key.

```js
var data = {
  "banana": 1,
  'lorem': 2,
  '123ana': 3
}

var result = _.filter(data, function(v, k) {
  return _.includes(k, 'ana');
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you want an object, which properties conform to a certain criterion, you can use [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pickBy) in a similar way.

```js
var data = {
  "banana": 1,
  'lorem': 2,
  '123ana': 3
}

var result = _.pickBy(data, function(v, k) {
  return _.includes(k, 'ana');
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I set your answer as the answer because it is a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

You could reach desired result using native `Array#reduce` and return an object containing only these keys, which includes given `string`.

```js
const obj = {
  banana: 'foo',
  hello: 'bar',
  foo: 'fzz',
  ana: 'xoo',
}

const check = (obj, str) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((s, a) => {
    if (a.includes(str)) {
      s[a] = obj[a];
    }
    return s;
  }, {});
}

console.log(check(obj, 'ana'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `filter()` to get keys with specific part of string and then `map()` to get values.

```js
var data = {
  "banana": 1,
  'lorem': 2,
  '123ana': 3
}

var result = _.chain(data)
  .keys()
  .filter(e => _.includes(e, 'ana'))
  .map(e => data[e])
  .value()
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```